# Devise will not save to database due to belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.1

After adding the marked line to my Devise user model in a Rails app I can no longer create new users in either the web form or using User.create() on the console. Commenting out this line restores full functionality. Obviously it is very closely related to the line above, it is so that I can have users assigned to a dealership. Any suggestions how to fix or do it differently as I need this functionality?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable

  has_many :tanks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :properties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stations
  has_many :clients, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :manager_id
  belongs_to :dealer, :class_name => 'User' #<--- this one
end
```

Comment: lets try the given solution below and let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
belongs_to :dealer, :class_name => "User",foreign_key: "dealer_id", optional: true
```

Note: - make sure you should have `dealer_id` in `User` model also to make it working `@user.dealer if @user.dealer.present?`

> Reason

- In Rails 5, whenever we define a `belongs_to association`, it is required to have the associated record present by default.

Comment: feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you, i have also added explanation. also make sure one thing you will have to pass `dealer_id` at the time of record creation so that you can use `@user.dealer`